insufficient funds for gas * price + value. when i use smart contract method in android using web3j
it showing that error -
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: insufficient funds for gas * price + value: balance 424719341670768841, queued cost 422740452000000000, tx cost 36900000000000000, overshot 34921110329231159
Need - gas fees should be just only 2% part of balance! Ex - balance 4247Eth, gas fee - 84.94eth (2%)
and my code it is -
NFTRewardsTheme {
    // Initialize Web3j and Credentials
    web3j = Web3j.build(HttpService(INFURA_URL))
    credentials = Credentials.create(PRIVATE_KEY)
    
    // Define the contract address
    val contractAddress = "0x6160D0Ca6ad8AA9Cc68d143D01591d8050b7dD9f"
    
    // Load the contract
    balanceChecker = FirstContract.load(contractAddress, web3j, credentials, DefaultGasProvider())

    // Fetch account balance in a coroutine
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        fetchAccountBalance("0x1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef12345678")
    }
}

// Function to fetch account balance
private fun fetchAccountBalance(address: String) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        try {
            Log.d("balance", "Starting balance call for address: $address\nContract Address: ${balanceChecker.contractAddress}")
            
            // Fetch the balance
            val balance = balanceChecker.getBalance(address).send()
            Log.d("balance", "Fetched balance: ${balance.toString()}")

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("balance", "Error fetching balance", e)
            
            // Check if the error is due to insufficient funds
            if (e is RuntimeException && e.message?.contains("insufficient funds") == true) {
                Log.e("balance", "Insufficient funds for gas. Please ensure your account has enough Ether.")
            }
        }
    }

